# Finding ids above average pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a graph where the x axis is the date and the y axis is the value and each line is a unique customer

[sample graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PScj1.png)

This is made with a data frame with the following structure:

```
  date     |cust_id|value
  01/01/18 |1      |2349
  02/01/18 |1      |242
  04/01/18 |1      |24429
  06/01/18 |1      |21412
  01/01/19 |2      |2349
```

The average line is made by taking the average value for each date:

```
agg = df.groupby('date').agg('mean').reset_index()
```

How can I isolate the IDs that are above the average line?

Answer (score 0):

```
df.merge(df.groupby('date').agg(m=('value','mean')).reset_index(),
         on='date').query('value >= m').drop(columns=['m'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `transform` to align the grouped mean with the original values and compare:

```
means = df.groupby('date')['value'].transform('mean')

df[df['value'] > means]
```

Answer (score 0):

Transform, boolean select to extract dataframe

```
df=df.assign(agg=df.groupby('date').cust_idvalue.transform('mean'))
df[df['cust_idvalue']>df['agg']]


      date  cust_idvalue    agg
04/01/18     1         24429  12108
06/01/18     1         21412  12108
```

Comment: cust_id and value are separate fields so I am not sure why you are combining them?